# Php Mysqli Undefined Function

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin, mysqli, connection

When executing the

```
mysqli_bind_result();
```

I receive an error saying "Call to undefined function".

My code looks as follows:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "*****");
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    if($_POST['username']){
    if($_POST['password']){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $passwordtmp = $_POST['password'];
    $password = md5(md5($passwordtmp));
    //Connect to Database//
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }
    //Check if user exist in database//
    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows == 1){
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")){
            mysqli_execute($stmt);
                    mysqli_bind_result($stmt,$passw);
                    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        $pass = $passw;  
                    }
```

Additional Information:

1. I transfered this code from a different computer to my laptop using the same connection to my mysql database.

   ```
       $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "*****");
   ```

   1. I copied the exact database to my laptop and both my computer and laptop are using wamp.
   2. I am wondering if this could be a connection to the database issue, or just a coding error.  But it works perfectly on my original computer without any problems.

Thank you in advance. I will give credit for helpful answers.

Comment: You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app. http://bobby-tables.com/php.html has examples to get you started.

Comment: You're mixing OOP usage and functional usage of the mysqli. While it will probably work, you'd benefit from keeping it consistent to aid readability and maintenance. As a comment to @AndyLester - mysqli is perfectly capable of parameterized queries, so there is no significant reason to switch to PDO at this point.

Comment: I do relieze I am doing that.  I have taken over this code from another person, and am in the process of switching

Answer (score 5):

You're probably using PHP > 5.4, as the function `mysqli_bind_result` was removed in PHP 5.4.

Change it to [`mysqli_stmt_bind_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) and that should fix your problem.

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $passw);
```